# how to achieve HiveQL error handling

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have multiple queries in a hql file (say 10, every query ending with ;) which I am running from a shell script.

When a query in between fails (say query #5), the queries after 5 do not execute, and the hive job is completed.

How can I do error handling to make sure that queries from 6 to 10 run even though query 5 fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Demo

**myscript.sql**

```
select 1;
select assert_true(false);
select 2;
```

### Option 1

```
hive --hiveconf hive.cli.errors.ignore=true -f myscript.sql
```

---

```
OK
1
Time taken: 3.742 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: ASSERT_TRUE(): assertion failed.
Time taken: 0.264 seconds
OK
2
Time taken: 0.284 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

### Option 2

```
hive<myscript.sql
```

---

```
hive> select 1;
OK
1
Time taken: 3.181 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select assert_true(false);
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: ASSERT_TRUE(): assertion failed.
Time taken: 0.335 seconds
hive> select 2;
OK
2
Time taken: 0.225 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Thank you... I was looking exactly for this.